# Unable to select specific dates in pivot filters area

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hi I am trying to add multiple dates in a Pivot to the "filters" area based the start and end date given in the cells.

Below is the code i used

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters. _
Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CLng(Range("Datefrom").Value), Value2:=CLng(Range("Dateto").Value)
```

Note: The above code works fine when i have the "Date" in the "Rows" area but i want it to work in the "filters" area.

I also recorded a macro and found that i have set the visible property for my dates and i do not have any clue on the same.
Appreciate your timely help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Filters area doesn't support the Dates Between filtering type. A workaround is to use a TimeLine Slicer if you have a version of Excel that supports them. (I think you need Excel 2013 or later)

[image]

If you want to use VBA to set the upper and lower limits to display, just turn on the Macro recorder, change the TimeLine, and then go inspect the code that the Macro recorder churned out.

If you've got an earlier version of Excel or need something slightly different let me know by amending your answer.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thank you for your time and effort, I tried your answer it is working fine. Thank you once again !!!